# apply with split function: 'expand' is an invalid keyword argument for split()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have below dataframe,

```
MID     C_PG                    ACT
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     ['view_goal,view_card']
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     ['expand,view_goal,select,add_activity']
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     ['view_goal_list']
```

And I want to transform it to below dataframe by splitting the string in 'ACT' column and rename the columns:

```
MID     C_PG                    step1        step2        step3      step4
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     view_goal    view_card    na         na
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     expand       view_goal    select     add_activity
GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2     view_goal    na           na         na
```

What I have tried:

```
df = df.set_index(['MID', 'C_PG']).apply(lambda x: str(x).split(',', expand=True))
```

But I got error:

> 'expand' is an invalid keyword argument for split()

Can anyone please provide a solution?

Comment: Does me answer below resolved your problem, if yes please accept my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, make sure to `import re` first :

```
import re

df['ACT'] = df['ACT'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("\[|]|'",'',x))
df = df.join(df['ACT'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('step')).fillna('na')
df = df.drop(columns=['ACT'])
```

Output :

```
    MID     C_PG                step0           step1       step2   step3
0   GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2 view_goal       view_card   na      na
1   GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2 expand          view_goal   select  add_activity
2   GOAL    PERFORMANCE_GOAL_V2 view_goal_list  na          na      na
```